# MySQL Server wont Start after Yum Upgrade

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

After executing yum update on my CentOS Cloud Server the MySQL doesn't start.

After searching on web for the error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I tryed to search for the file mysql.sock through find and grep but didn't succeded. The error log of mysql, after trying to start it in safe mode is:

```
130529 13:51:18  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130529 13:51:23  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 43655
130529 13:51:23 [Note]
130529 13:51:23 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
130529 14:15:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130529 14:15:52 [ERROR] Error message file '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' had only 481 error messages,
but it should contain at least 641 error messages.
Check that the above file is the right version for this program!
130529 14:15:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/libexec/mysqld: Unknown error 1146
130529 14:15:52 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
130529 14:15:52  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130529 14:15:52  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130529 14:15:53  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43655
130529 14:15:53 [ERROR] Aborting

130529 14:15:53  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130529 14:15:58  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 43655
130529 14:15:58 [Note]
130529 14:15:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Hope you guys can help me, i can provide any information you need, just tell me how can i help you helping me out.

EDIT:
Tryed to chwon the files for mysql and chmod that either.

Before negative flagging me, look what i wrote, i've already used MYSQL_UPGRADE and the error is the same about socket.

```
[root@cpro5022mysql]# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error there in your log which explain what's going wrong. `[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.` means that your `mysql` table's schema is out of date and needs to be upgraded.

Comment: Here is the code when i run mysql_upgrade:
[root@cpro5022 mysql]# mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck with default connection arguments
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed